# Get media from public accounts with instagram API

Tags: api, token, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working for a company that displays content on big screens located on public places like GYMs or waiting rooms.

One client asked app that shows `Instagram` content from celebrities accounts, so I created one using the `Instagram API`.

The problem is that the app is in `sandbox mode` and it gets blank data.

It seems I can only show media from sandbox users (not Beyonce), when I submitted for review it was rejected because it doesn't meet the requirements.

Is there a way to make it work?

During tests I used a valid access token I found on internet, but I don't think that is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, when app is in `sandbox mode` you are only able to see data on Instagram from sandbox users which you have set in advance. You won't get any public data on `Instagram` in this mode.

According to the API, your app doesn't have the criteria required to get approved.

From the [`Permissions Review`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) page:

> **Valid Use Cases**
>
> We will approve submissions of apps that fall into these use cases:
>
> - To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps
> - To help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and
>     digital media rights
> - To help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital > rights to media, and share media with proper attribution

They also listed use cases of applications that won't get approval and it seems like your app matches one of them:

> Here are some examples of scenarios that will not be approved:
>
> - **One-off projects**. If you are an agency building websites or other integrations, note that we don't grant permissions to clients created
>     for one-off projects. If you are interested in building a product,
>     platform, or widget that will be used as a service across multiple
>     projects, then you may submit a single client_id that you can use
>     across multiple projects
>     ...

To get approved you should modify your application to correspond with criteria, perhaps build multiple projects?

You can also try to pull down the data from this `URL`:  `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/media/`

For [`Beyonce`](https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/) account, use: `https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/media/`

Lastly, the `access token` is unique per-app, so you can't be using a random one. Here is a tutorial on [`how to generate access token`](http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token) for your app.

Comment: Hey the link you gave me worked great, thanks! Also I realized that all the information I need is at the source code of the instagram page of the person. Just fetch the source code using php and look for the section (window._sharedData), it includes the info (followers, etc) and the media. That way I don't need to use the API, do you think there might be an inconvenient using this method?

Comment: I think using the `/media` URL is probably more reliable and less exposed to changes, but whatever works for you.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets an error if enters `https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/media/` in the browser?